# Use a generating function to count the number of combinations with limited repetition

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

> What's the number of multisets of size five of $\{A, B, C, D, E\}$ if some letter occurs at least three times?

Using PIE we see the answer to this problem is $75.$ Though, I am not quite sure how to set up a generating function here.

I do know that

> The product $(1 + X)(1 + X+ X^2)(1 + X + X^2 + X^3)$ is called the generating
>   function for counting combinations from a three-element set, when one element
>   can be selected at most once, another at most twice, and the third at most three
>   times. The coefficient of $X^k$ in the product is equal to the number of $k$-element combinations that satisfy these conditions.

Using the quote above as a guide I tried $(1 + X)^2(1 + X^3 + X^4 + X^5),$ but that seems wrong. What am I doing wrong here? How can I fix that? Thanks.

Comment: Your attempted g.f. counts the number of ways to choose 0 or 1 As, 0 or 1 Bs, and 0,3,4, or 5 Cs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because order doesn't matter, you can create a combination by choosing the number of $A$s, then choosing the number of $B$s, etc.

The act of choosing between $p$ and $q$ of the same letter is represented by the factor $(x^p+x^{p+1}+\ldots+x^q)$. For example, choosing between $0$ and $2$ $B$s is represented by $1+x+x^2$.

If you can choose any number of a particular letter, the factor in the g.f. is $\frac1{1-x}$. For two letters, this becomes $\frac1{(1-x)^2}$.

Now let $f(x)$ be the g.f. representing the choice of any number of each of the five letters.

Then let $g(x)$ be the g.f. representing the choice of $0,1,$ or $2$ of each of the five letters.

Then the needed g.f. is $f(x)-g(x)$.

---

If you absolutely need to find a coefficient by hand, use $$\frac1{(1-x)^n}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\binom{n-1+i}{i}x^i$$and $$(1+x+x^2)^n=\sum_{i+j+k=n}\binom{n}{i,j,k}x^{j+2k}$$
In that last one, the coefficient of any specific term $x^p$ is a sum of several multinomials.

Comment: So the answer should be $\frac{1}{(1 - x)^5} - \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2}$?

Comment: The second term is wrong: that means choosing any number of As and Bs. You want 0,1, or 2 of each of five different letters.

Comment: For example, choosing 0-3 copies of seven different letters would be $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^7$

Comment: Oh I see I gotta work on my series expansion skills. What's the explicit formula for $(1 + x + x^2)^5$?  Sorry for asking :) Haven't taken Calculus yet so I am not really sure how this series thing works.

Comment: If this is homework, then my guess is that you are allowed to just write down the basic g.f. without expanding it out (but you can use Wolfram Alpha).

Comment: Thanks for going above and beyond. Your answer resolves my problem 1000%.

Comment: If in fact you need to expand $(1+x+x^2)^5$, you may find it helps to re-write it as $(1-x^3)^5 \cdot (1-x)^{-5}$.